# Should I add the ionic 2 libraries into the repository?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

For example, CocoaPods [recommends](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) iOS users to put everything into the version controlling system. How should I handle ionic 2 libraries? Is there such an official recommendation?

Comment: What do you mean with ionic 2 libraries? Plugins? As far as i know there is no official recommendation but you should exclude everything from version-control that is create dynamically by cordova or ionic. So put the following folders in your .gitignore: `node_modules`, `platforms`, `plugins`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `node_modules` is excluded  in .gitignore and .tfignore, but for other folders there's no recomendation.

You can ignore `platforms` folder too, it's heavy and there's no need to version it since every person who gets your code will have to add platforms since there can be some environment divergeces.

`Plugins` is not needed too, when adding platforms the plugins will be instaled, you'll just need to make sure the plugins version are correct.

`www` is a folder you need 'cause cordova will crash if this folder is not present, but you don't need the content inside it be cause in every build it'll clean this folder and create content again, so if you want you can have only your folder.

Everything else you can version controll. Hope this helps.